# Encontrar documento que originou os seguintes

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma tabela em que um documento pode originar novos documentos, e este novo documento carrega  em uma coluna o número do documento originador(não necessariamente o primeiro documento que existiu).

Pode haver diversos documentos depois do originador, mas preciso encontrar sempre o primeiro documento.
No exemplo o documento 112 gerou o 117, que gerou o 119, que gerou o 120, que gerou o 121, mas o originador de tudo, é o 112.

Anexei imagens para tentar deixar mais claro o que desejo fazer, também script para criar a tabela e  uma tentativa de alcançar o objetivo.

Tabela:

[image: Tabela]

Desejado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link arquivos](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Arquivos%20F%C3%B3rum/SQL%20Server/num_doc)

Agradeço se puderem ajudar.

O ideal seria independentemete de quantos documentos existirem eu conseguir chegar ao originador, mas se tiver que fazer para uma quantidade fixa de documentos, creio que também serve ao propósito.
Inclusive sobre o título da pergunta, não consegui pensar em algo melhor. Aceito críticas para poder deixar mais coerente com a necessidade.

tentativa:

```
 SELECT cliente,num_doc,num_doc_anterior,
 (SELECT( IIF((num_doc_anterior =''),(num_doc),
 (IIF((num_doc_anterior<>''),
 (select num_doc from DADOS where num_doc =dd.num_doc_anterior),
 'XXX'))))) AS doc_original
 FROM DADOS dd
```

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que cada cliente possua apenas num `doc_original` daria pra fazer assim:

```
WITH    q AS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    dados
        WHERE   num_doc_anterior IS NULL -- this condition defines the ultimate ancestors in your chain, change it as appropriate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  m.*
        FROM    dados m
        JOIN    q
        ON      m.num_doc = q.num_doc_anterior
        )
SELECT  d.*, q.num_doc as doc_original
FROM    q inner join dados d on
q.cliente = d.cliente
```

link para o [sqlfiddle com o exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cab98/4/0)

Comment: Lucas MIranda, sua sugestão vai funcionar somente se os campos forem `int`?

Comment: não, eu fiz int no fiddler pois não sabia o tipo dos seus dados, lembrando que se o id do cliente tiver mais de um doc_original, esse join não vai dar bom

Comment: Vou verificar pela manhã,  e sobre cada cliente ter somente um `doc_original`, pode acontecer de ter mais de um caso, cada `doc_original` originando outros documentos. Não lembrei de incluir isto no exemplo.

Comment: de fato não deu bom, na sua sugestão, é possível contornar isto? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/616d5/1

Comment: Exemplo mais completo ( com mais situações)  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/806e15/1